# the selected value of the DropdownButtonFormField appears only when I reload the whole app

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I need this alert dialog to display the selected item in the

```
Widget _changePrPar() {
  showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return SingleChildScrollView(
          child: AlertDialog(
            key: alertDialogKey,
            title: ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
              title: Text("Mon premier Dialogue"),
            ),
            content: Form(
              key: formKey,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "Nom et Prenom",
                        hintText: "Ex. Ndoume Desmon"),
                    validator: (val) =>
                        val.isEmpty ? "The Name cannot be empty" : null,
                    onSaved: (val) => nomP = val,
                  ),

                  TextFormField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: "User Name",
                          hintText: "Ex. desmon215"),
                      validator: (val) => val.isEmpty
                          ? "The user name cannot be empty"
                          : null,
                      onSaved: (val) => pseudo = val),

                  //My Problems start here, the value selected does not appear,
                  ListTile(
                    title: Text(
                      "Gender",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                    ),
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 9),
                    subtitle: DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
                      items: Sexe.map((l) => DropdownMenuItem(
                            child: Text(l),
                            value: l,
                          )).toList(),
                      value: sexyVal,
                      onSaved: (val) => sexyVal = val,
                      onChanged: (v) {
                        setState(() {
                          sexyVal = v;
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: "Telephone",
                          hintText: "Ex. 654521455"),
                      validator: (val) =>
                          val.length > 9 && val.startsWith("6")
                              ? null
                              : "The phoe number is not valid..",
                      onSaved: (val) => tel = val),
                  TextFormField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: "Email",
                          hintText: "Ex. abc@xyzer.com"),
                      validator: (val) =>
                          val.contains("@") && val.endsWith(".com")
                              ? null
                              : "Invalid e-mail",
                      onSaved: (val) => mailP = val),
                  TextFormField(
                      controller: passCtl,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        suffix: IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.cancel,
                            color: Colors.grey,
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            passCtl.clear();
                          },
                        ),
                        labelText: "PassWord",
                        hintText: "8 caracters minimum..",
                      ),
                      maxLengthEnforced: true,
                      maxLength: 10,
                      obscureText: true,
                      validator: (val) =>
                          val.length < 8 ? "Password too short" : null,
                      onSaved: (val) => pass = val),
                  TextFormField(
                    controller: dateCtl,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      suffix: IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.cancel,
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          dateCtl.clear();
                        },
                      ),
                      labelText: "Date of birth",
                      hintText: "Ex. Insert your dob",
                    ),
                    onTap: () async {
                      DateTime date = DateTime(1900);
                      FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
                      date = await showDatePicker(
                          context: context,
                          initialDate: DateTime.now(),
                          firstDate: DateTime(1900),
                          lastDate: DateTime(2100));

                      // pour calculer l'age a partir de la date de naissance
                      age = DateTime.now().difference(date).inDays;
                      Age = (age / 360).floor();
                      _date = date.toIso8601String();
                      dateCtl.text = _date.substring(0, 10);
                    },
                    onSaved: (val) => _date = Age.toString(),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                child: Text("Cancel"),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              ),
              FlatButton(
                child: Text("Submit"),
                onPressed: () {
                  final form = formKey.currentState;
                  if (form.validate()) {
                    setState(() {
                      form.save();
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    });
                  }
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
        );
      });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to build a class extending `StatefulWidget`,and move your content of the dialog inside the build method,

```
class DialogContent extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_DialogContentState createState() => _DialogContentState();
}

class _DialogContentState extends State<DialogContent> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return SingleChildScrollView(
  child: AlertDialog(
    key: alertDialogKey,
    title: ListTile(
      leading: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
      title: Text("Mon premier Dialogue"),
    ),
    content: Form(
      key: formKey,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: "Nom et Prenom",
                hintText: "Ex. Ndoume Desmon"),
            validator: (val) =>
            val.isEmpty ? "The Name cannot be empty" : null,
            onSaved: (val) => nomP = val,
          ),

          TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "User Name",
                  hintText: "Ex. desmon215"),
              validator: (val) => val.isEmpty
                  ? "The user name cannot be empty"
                  : null,
              onSaved: (val) => pseudo = val),

          //My Problems start here, the value selected does not appear,
          ListTile(
            title: Text(
              "Gender",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
            ),
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 9),
            subtitle: DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
              items: Sexe.map((l) => DropdownMenuItem(
                child: Text(l),
                value: l,
              )).toList(),
              value: sexyVal,
              onSaved: (val) => sexyVal = val,
              onChanged: (v) {
                setState(() {
                  sexyVal = v;
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
          TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "Telephone",
                  hintText: "Ex. 654521455"),
              validator: (val) =>
              val.length > 9 && val.startsWith("6")
                  ? null
                  : "The phoe number is not valid..",
              onSaved: (val) => tel = val),
          TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "Email",
                  hintText: "Ex. abc@xyzer.com"),
              validator: (val) =>
              val.contains("@") && val.endsWith(".com")
                  ? null
                  : "Invalid e-mail",
              onSaved: (val) => mailP = val),
          TextFormField(
              controller: passCtl,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                suffix: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.cancel,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    passCtl.clear();
                  },
                ),
                labelText: "PassWord",
                hintText: "8 caracters minimum..",
              ),
              maxLengthEnforced: true,
              maxLength: 10,
              obscureText: true,
              validator: (val) =>
              val.length < 8 ? "Password too short" : null,
              onSaved: (val) => pass = val),
          TextFormField(
            controller: dateCtl,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              suffix: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.cancel,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  dateCtl.clear();
                },
              ),
              labelText: "Date of birth",
              hintText: "Ex. Insert your dob",
            ),
            onTap: () async {
              DateTime date = DateTime(1900);
              FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
              date = await showDatePicker(
                  context: context,
                  initialDate: DateTime.now(),
                  firstDate: DateTime(1900),
                  lastDate: DateTime(2100));

              // pour calculer l'age a partir de la date de naissance
              age = DateTime.now().difference(date).inDays;
              Age = (age / 360).floor();
              _date = date.toIso8601String();
              dateCtl.text = _date.substring(0, 10);
            },
            onSaved: (val) => _date = Age.toString(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    actions: <Widget>[
      FlatButton(
        child: Text("Cancel"),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
        },
      ),
      FlatButton(
        child: Text("Submit"),
        onPressed: () {
          final form = formKey.currentState;
          if (form.validate()) {
            setState(() {
              form.save();
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            });
          }
        },
       )
      ],
     ),
    );
  });
 }
}
```

And now just return it to the `showDialog`

```
showDialog(
....
builder: (context)=> DialogContent()
);
```

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Comment: the issue with this solution is that the data modified does not have an immediate effect on the variables, you need to reload the page in other to see the modifications....

Comment: but it helped me a lot, and I am greatful, just that another issue has been raised again, I am forced to reload the page in other to see the modifications

Comment: Other Modifications Like?

Comment: When I call the dialog box it comes fine I insert datas, but when I save the data are not updated directly in the profile page